# Temporarily adding attributes to mongoengine documents

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I'm using Flask with mongoengine and I am trying to pass in one extra attribute to a jinja template that is not in the model definition.

Something like, models.py:

```
class Report(Document):

    date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
```

And then in reports.py:

```
...

report = models.Report.objects(id=report_id).first()
report.new_attr = "New"

resp = render_template(('report.html'), report=report)

return resp

...
```

I want to be able to use `{{ new_attr }}` in the template but not `.save()`  it to the object. So far the new attribute is not showing up in the object even when printed.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but why do this? Why not send the value directly to the template as a separate variable?

```
 resp = render_template(('report.html') ,new_attr = "New", report=report)
```